# Quiero convertir tipo Int a su correspondiente numero de la tabla ASCII

Tags: c

```
int i=2;
int caracterAscii=  ¿    ?
```

debería devolver el numero 50.

¿Cómo he de hacerlo?

Comment: http://ascii.cl/es/ Pero vamos, que en Google salen tropecientos enlaces a la tabla ASCII.

Comment: Así, tal y como lo preguntas ... ¿¿ 52 - i ?? ¿¿ 48 + i ?? No se yo si alguien se molestaría en hacer una función para eso ...

Comment: `int ascii(char t) { return (int)t; }` Creo que es suficiente si tu intención es obtener un digito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i=2;
```

Ya empiezas mal. Si quieres convertir un caracter a entero **tienes que usar un caracter**:

```
char i='2';
```

Vale, ahora ¿cómo se convierte en entero? Deberías saber que el tipo `char` es un **entero de 1 byte** con signo, luego la conversión es instantánea:

```
char i='2';
int numero = (int)i;
printf("%d %d",numero,i);
```

De hecho puedes ver en el ejemplo anterior que no haría ni falta pasarlo a `int`.

¿Por qué funciona?

Como te he comentado, el tipo `char` no es más que un entero de 8 bytes, es decir, un número. Lo que sucede es que a la hora de imprimirlo el sistema operativo no imprime el número directamente, sino que se va a una tabla de traducción de donde extrae el caracter ASCII correspondiente.

Comment: Números del 0 al 9, _¡No más de ahí!_ pd: Creo que no es necesario el cast de `char` a `int`, según lo que mencionas al final, a no ser que utilices `gcc`, ese compilador es loco. :P

Comment: @NaCl me da la impresión de que no se ha expresado bien y lo que quiere es obtener el valor numérico de un caracter ASCII. Si te fijas verás que el dígito 2 se corresponde con el valor 50. En cuanto a lo de la conversión efectivamente es supérflua, pero como yo suelo vivir en C++ y ahí si aportan claridad vivo con ese vicio

Comment: `no se ha expresado bien` es una forma suave de decirlo. Ha preguntado como sumar o restar 2 enteros. No soy partidario de contestar esto, al menos hasta que edite la pregunta y la clarifique un poco.

Comment: @NaCl lo se, por eso el `printf` de mi respuesta es doble

Comment: @Dolmenes todos hemos empezado a programar desde cero en algun momento... y en ese punto es facil equivocarse al intentar expresar el problema que uno tiene... yo he visto cosas peores en mi etapa en la universidad

Comment: @eferion Aunque yo me habría ahorrado el cast `(int)i`, pues el especificador de formato lo dice todo, pero supongo que es para mostrarle al op.

Comment: @NaCl esa era la idea. Dejar conversiones implícitas en manos de un novato es como sugerirle que por debajo hay magia negra o vuduu jejeje

Comment: ¡Python detected! Jajaja :P

Comment: @eferion de acuerdo en que los comienzos son difíciles. Nada que objetar a eso. Pero un mínimo de cuidado al preguntar ... no se, mostrar un mínimo de interés en expresar bien la pregunta. Es mi opinión tan solo.

Comment: @Dolmenes para eso están los comentarios, para intentar ilustar a los nuevos sobre cómo se deben redactar las preguntas

Comment: @eferion pues eso decía yo: esperar a que sea comprensible, con comentarios en la pregunta, **antes** de responder. Pero vamos, que es tan solo mi *modus operandi*. Cada uno tiene su forma de hacer las cosas :-)

Answer (score -2):

48 + i

Funcionaria para 0 a 9. Si tienes un numero mayor de 9, dos digitos o n digitos podrias usar alguna funcion como itoa que le pasas el numero int, un buffer para el string y la base (generalmente 10).

Comment: La respuesta en sí se antoja incompleta. Considera incluir un ejemplo en código para que la respuesta sea más clara. Piensa que a esta pregunta llegará gente que está empezando y que posee escasos conceptos sobre el lenguaje C. (PD.:  el negativo no es mío)

Comment: Adicional, [`itoa`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162829/5622844) no es parte de un estandar, según leo...

Comment: Claro, la respuesta es valida, quiza no sea la mejor, pero depende del contexto en el que se obtenga i, si el i viene de un readChar() entonces por alguna extraña razon necesitas el codigo ascii, mi respuesta es mas acertada que la tuya. En fin... si en realidad lo que se necesita es saber si la tecla que se apreto es 2 entonces tiene mas sentido comprar directamente con 2, algo asi como readChar() == (int)'2', quiza no deberia responder preguntas mal formuladas :)

Comment: @NaCl eso realmente importa? En la pregunta no es explicito a usar funciones unicamente del standard, admas es una sugerencia dependiendo de lo que necesita, se justificaria un down vote por eso?

Comment: Yo no he dado el downvote, sólo hice una adición a lo que menciona @eferion arriba, no puedes enseñar algo que no sabes si funcionará en la plataforma para la que desarrolla el op.

Comment: Efectivamente. Si algo no es acorde al estándar debes indicar dicha restricción. Las mejores respuestas suelen adaptarse al estándar o a las librerías que ya está usando el OP